# Saving multiple strings in Android memory for use later

Tags: android, sql

I have an app that generates five strings every time I use it and I want these strings saved for use later, ie. when I open and run the app again.  When I use the app the second time I want to save the new five stings for use later along with the first five strings I generated the first time I ran the app.  On and on until I have say 10 sets of these five strings.

I and confused as to what it the best way to do this, Internal Memory, sql database, etc.  could someone point me to a good example on the best practices for this.  My experience with sql databases is very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the android website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

To save:

```
// We need an Editor object to make preference changes. 
// All objects are from android.context.Context
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

// Commit the edits!
editor.commit();
```

To load:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Sqlite** would be the best practice in my opinion
also u could have used `SharedPreferences` if you had a fixed number of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SharedPreferences` for storing strings

Answer (score 1):

Android actually provides you a wide range of Storage Mechanisms like,

1. Shared Preference
2. Sqlite
3. File
4. External or Internal    Directories.

take a look at these: [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and [Data Storage Mechanisms in Android](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/17/data-storage-mechanisms-in-android/)